# UIView animateWithDuration:animations:completion: blocks don't comile in an .mm file

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, xcode4

I have the following code in an .mm file:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    self.titleLabel.alpha = 0.0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {    //<<compiler complains here
    self.titleLabel.alpha = 1.0;
}];
```

But I get the compiler error:

> Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'void (^)(BOOL)' with an rvalue of type 'void (^)(int)'

on the line mentioned above. The code is fine in a normal .m file. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a problem with the compiler?

UPDATE: Header imports are:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

and .mm imports are (censored):

```
#import "XXSelectViewController.h"
#import "XXViewController.h"
#import "AboutViewController.h"
#import "HighScoresViewController.h"
#import "GameModel.h"
```

UPDATE 2: Also, I get a warning on this line:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

warning:

> Conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'viewDidDisappear:': 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') vs 'int'

We are using the PowerVR tools in this project, and in PVRShell.h and PVRTResourceFile.h are the following lines:

```
typedef bool (*PFNReleaseFileFunc)(void* handle);

typedef bool (*PFNReleaseFileFunc)(void* handle);
```

I don't know if this has anything to do with the issues though...

Comment: just try to cast finished to bool type :)

Comment: Can you show the #imports from the header and .mm file for the .mm version?

Comment: its looks like a typedef for BOOL is not right.

Comment: @stackmonster - added to the question above :)

Comment: @AalokParikh - finished is already `BOOL`...?

Comment: Yes but in .mm it may be considered as int so it gives this error :)

Comment: So how do I change it then? If I just change it to `^(int finished)` I still get the same error :(

Comment: Have you updated to Xcode 4.4.1?

Comment: @JesseRusak no, I'm on 4.4 at the moment... I could update, but I'm working with someone who is on 4.3 so it would still be an issue for him. Could try though!

Comment: It might not matter. I'm also not sure that the lines you posted from the PowerVR tools would have any impact; they're defining a type called "handle". Is there anything else in your headers that could be causing this problem? Have you tried looking at the preprocessed source for the lines giving you an error?

Comment: Checked on the App store, and it doesn't appear as an update for me yet anyway. Sorry for being ignorant, but how do I look at preprocessed source?

Comment: @JesseRusak - I just found it under the "Generate Output" so I ran it on the file and the output is *massive*... I did a search for `animateWithDuration` and it is in there, but I don't see any issues or comments around it...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the reason for the errors is because of this line, buried deep within the PVR Tools:

```
#define BOOL int
```

So there's a macro going through all of the code, replacing `BOOL` with `int`. Not ideal! I think the reason it's causing a problem is because the tools were added as a folder and not as an embedded .xcodeproj ... So we may need to re-import it. Lesson learned!

Bizarrely though, if I comment out that line, the code still works ;) but who knows for how long!

Comment: This is the kind of issue you could find via the preprocessed output; if you look at the line giving the problem, it probably says `int` instead of `BOOL` in the preprocessed source.

Comment: I see... Just tried it! Think I get it a bit more now. Thanks!